# Upload form not working - File is being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net, xml, file-upload, linq-to-xml

I've got a C# file upload that is meant to extract XML tags from inside a DocX document, the problem I'm facing is that when the file is uploaded, the error "File is being used by another process" comes up. Attempting to delete the document shows it is being used by IIS process manager.

Is there a way to stop my code to get it to continue running?

```
<script runat="server">


 //foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
 //{
  //  string dbColumnNames = (selectedData.ToString());
     //send files
 //}

    public string _TempFileLocation = ""; //Used to locate Word Document File Path 


        //THE USER UPLOAD CONTROL. users use this to upload the document to the server
        public void XMLextractor(string _filePath)
        {
            //XML extraction code
           displayFilepath.Text = _filePath;
           _TempFileLocation = _filePath;

        }

        //names the script manager which will be used when the user attempts to upload a form / gives an error if they incorrectly attempt to upload
        protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if file is located
            if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
            {
                try
                {
                    //allow content type of document / docx
                    if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
                    {

                        if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength < 10485760) // 10mb)
                        {
                            //name the filename, find the path of the name
                            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                            //path of server upload (we just need to save it as a variable to be found on the next page, as it will be made / deleted
                            FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
                            //update the label with file uploaded
                            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";

                            XMLextractor(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);

                            //move onto template wizard page
                            //Response.Redirect("http://portal.acoura.com/admin/templatewizard.aspx", false);

                            WordprocessingDocument _TempDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename, true);

                            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
                            //query to find particular descendants
                            var lv1s = from document in xdoc.Descendants("table")
                                       select new
                                       {
                                           Header = document.Attribute("name").Value,
                                           Children = document.Descendants("tag")
                                       };

                            //Loop through results
                            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                            foreach (var lv1 in lv1s)
                                        {
                                            result.AppendLine(lv1.Header);
                                            foreach (var lv2 in lv1.Children)
                                            result.AppendLine("     " + lv2.Attribute("name").Value);
                                        }

                            //the label should contain the content controls of the document, using the class, XMLfromDocument                                                                                                                                           
                            labelContentControls.Text = fileUpload_Displayx(XMLfromDocument.GetContentControls(_TempDoc));
                        }

                        else
                            //display the size the file needs to be less than
                            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file has to be less than 10mb!";
                    }
                    else
                        //tell the user only docx files are accepted
                        StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Only DOCX files are accepted!";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //display the exception message, in which case it would be either size / type / if it's present
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
                }


            }

        }

        //needs to be replaced with the variable found in descendants / var tagContent
        public string fileUpload_Displayx(XElement _contentcontrol)
        {
            string str = "";
            str = _contentcontrol.Name.ToString();

            return str;
        }


   //public static displayDatabase(object sender, EventArgs e)
  // {

   //}
   //run the validate button on templatewizard, will mark up any problems or give green light


   //if red, allow users to replace fields in the left column, from ones in the atabase on the right


   //display upload button when validation is succesful. When Upload button runs, Take to new 
   // / existing page of reports, allow users to download this 






</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the file without closing it on this line:

```
WordprocessingDocument _TempDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename, true);
```

Then you are opening it again with xDocument.Load():

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
```

I assume that is where the error occurs.

If you handle all of the stuff `XDocument` needs to do first, and then open and close the `WordProcessingDocument.Open()` line to get the content controls, you should be fine.

Basically only one process can have a open and read or modify a file at a time, so if two operations from two different sources need to be performed, they must be performed sequentially on the file.

You can also open the file via a FileStream and then load the content into memory and into your `XDocument`, therefore negating the need to have the file opened twice by `XDocument` and `WordProcessingDocument` simultaneously.

Hope this helps!